# How can I change the do_action function in footer (copyright area)

Tags: functions, themes, footer, copyright

Theme: Education LMS

How can I remove the theme information from my footer copyright area, or how can I edit the do_action function? So that only display what I want to display in footer.

```
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="site-info">
                        <?php  do_action( 'education_lms_footer_copyright' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .site-info -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
                        'menu_id'        => 'footer-menu',
                        'menu_class'     => 'pull-right list-unstyled list-inline mb-0'
                    ) );
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>'
```

I Found this, please tell me is this the right part?

```
<php
/**
* Add theme dashboard page
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'education_lms_theme_info');
function education_lms_theme_info() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    add_theme_page( sprintf( esc_html__( '%s Dashboard', 'education-lms' ), $theme_data->Name ), sprintf( '%s', $theme_data->Name), 'edit_theme_options', 'education_lms', 'education_lms_theme_info_page');
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'education_lms_admin_scripts' ) ) :
    /**
     * Enqueue scripts for admin page only: Theme info page
     */
    function education_lms_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
        if ( $hook === 'widgets.php' || $hook === 'appearance_page_education_lms'  ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('education_lms-admin-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css');
        }
    }
endif;
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'education_lms_admin_scripts');
function education_lms_theme_info_page() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    // Check for current viewing tab
    $tab = null;
    if ( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ) {
        $tab = $_GET['tab'];
    } else {
        $tab = null;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap about-wrap theme_info_wrapper">
        <h1><?php printf(esc_html__('Welcome to %1$1s - Version %2$2s', 'education-lms'), $theme_data->Name, $theme_data->Version ); ?></h1>
        <div class="about-text"><?php echo $theme_data->Description ></div>
        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=education_lms" class="nav-tab<?php echo is_null($tab) ? ' nav-tab-active' : null; ?>"><?php echo $theme_data->Name; ?></a>
            <?php ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'page'=>'education_lms', 'tab' => 'free_pro' ), admin_url( 'themes.php' ) ) ); ?>" class="nav-tab<?php echo $tab == 'free_pro' ? ' nav-tab-active' : null; ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Free vs PRO', 'education-lms' ); ?></span></a>
            <?php  ?>
        </h2>

        <?php if ( is_null($tab) ) { ?>
            <div class="theme_info info-tab-content">
                <div class="theme_info_column clearfix">
                    <div class="theme_info_left">

                        <div class="theme_link">
                            <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Theme Customizer', 'education-lms' ); ?></h3>
                            <p class="about"><?php printf(esc_html__('%s supports the Theme Customizer for all theme settings. Click "Customize" to start customize your site.', 'education-lms'), $theme_data->Name); ?></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="<?php echo admin_url('customize.php'); ?>" class="button button-primary"><?php esc_html_e('Start Customize', 'education-lms'); ?></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="theme_link">
                            <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Theme Documentation', 'education-lms' ); ?></h3>
                            <p class="about"><?php printf(esc_html__('Need any help to setup and configure %s? Please have a look at our documentations instructions.', 'education-lms'), $theme_data->Name); ?></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="http://docs.filathemes.com/education-lms/" target="_blank" class="button button-secondary"><?php esc_html_e('Online Documentation', 'education-lms'); ?></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="theme_info_right">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/screenshot.png" alt="<?php esc_html_e( 'Theme Screenshot', 'education-lms' ); ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php

        if ( $tab == 'free_pro' ) { ?>
            <div id="free_pro" class="freepro-tab-content info-tab-content">
                <table class="free-pro-table">
                    <thead><tr><th></th><th>Free</th><th> PRO</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Responsive Design</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Translation Ready</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Upload Your Own Logo</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Unlimited Slide</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>LearnPress - WordPress LMS</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Elementor Compatible</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>WooCommerce Compatible</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Custom Widgets</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Header Topbar</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Header Cover Image</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Social Icons</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Footer Widget</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Demo Content Ready</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Retina Logo</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Sticky Header</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Header Transparent</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>2 Header Layout</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Slider Advanced Styling</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Course Grid/List Layout</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Multi Color Options</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Back To Top</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>600+ Google fonts</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Footer Copyright & Layout</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h4>24/7/365 Support</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class="only-pro"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-no-alt"></span></td>
                        <td class="only-lite"><span class="dashicons-before dashicons-yes"></span></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr class="ti-about-page-text-center"><td></td><td colspan="2"><a href="https://www.filathemes.com/downloads/education-lms-pro/" target="_blank" class="button button-primary button-hero">Get Pro now!</a></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <?php }  ?>



    </div> <!-- END .theme_info -->

    <?php
}
function education_lms_admin_notice(){
    if ( version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0 ) {
        ?>
        <div class="warning notice notice-warning notice-alt is-dismissible">
            <p><strong><?php esc_html_e('The Education LMS theme require PHP version 5.4 or greater.', 'education-lms'); ?></strong></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
function education_lms_one_activation_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && ('themes.php' == $pagenow) && isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'education_lms_admin_notice' );
    }
}
/* activation notice */
add_action( 'load-themes.php',  'education_lms_one_activation_admin_notice'  );
function education_lms_review_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && 'themes.php' == $pagenow  ) {
        ?>
        <span id="footer-thankyou">
                <?php
                $reviewurl = 'https://wordpress.org/support/theme/education-lms/reviews/#new-post';
                printf( __( 'You have been using <b>Education LMS</b> theme, do you like it? If so, please leave us <a href="%s" target="_blank">a review</a> with your feedback. Thank you!', 'education-lms' ), esc_url( $reviewurl ) );
                ?>
        </span>
        <?php
    }
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'education_lms_review_notice');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing all actions as suggested by @kero, you should remove the desired hooks only using [`remove_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/). Removing all hooks will prevent 3rd party code from adding their code too when removed after they added their stuff (possibly including yours).

To remove a specific hook you should search for the code which registers the action. In this case:

```
// theme-functions.php:322
add_action( 'education_lms_footer_copyright', 'education_lms_footer_info' );
```

Then add your own code in your `functions.php` to remove the hook:

```
remove_action( 'education_lms_footer_copyright', 'education_lms_footer_info' );
```

To add custom code at the copyright position you could use something like:

```
add_action( 'education_lms_footer_copyright', function () {
 echo 'My copyright code';
} );
```

Sometimes you might need to pass a priority (3rd parameter) if the hook was registered with another than the default of `10`.

Comment: couldn't find footer or copyright related content in files. Can you please help me out here

Comment: Is this the right part ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I mean, that is this the right part to be edited?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to overwrite the PHP function in your child-themes functions.php. 
You can search in your parent theme for the original function `education_lms_footer_copyright`.

OR just type in your own information in the template if this would be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`remove_all_actions()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_all_actions/), but you have to make sure the theme's actions are actually set before you want to remove them. Setting a high enough priority could work.

```
add_action('init', 'WPSE_remove_lms_footer_copyright', 9999);
function WPSE_remove_lms_footer_copyright() {
    remove_all_actions('education_lms_footer_copyright');
}
```

Where to put this code? If you already have a custom plugin, you can use it there. If you don't, you can create a child theme and could use it there.

But if you already have a child theme, it will be much easier to copy the (presumably) footer.php and simply remove this line.

Comment: I have updated the content in question, please check and help me out here...